# Pandas Date Format Does not convert date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm using Pandas version 0.12.0 to import a csv file with dates

The dates are in the following format 'SEP2005'

using pandas to read the csv file:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv') 

mydata.head()
Out[40]: 
      Date  Quantity  
0  APR2002  282.0000     
1  APR2002  NaN     
2  APR2002  0.0000     
3  APR2002  20.2253     
4  APR2002  55.6853
```

I then turn the Date Column to the index using the follow:

```
mydata.index = pd.to_datetime(mydata.pop('Date'))
```

Here is what is very strange in the past it has parsed my dates and turned the format into

2002-04-15  which is what I want.  Then I would just make sure the days where set the the last day of the month:

```
mydate.index = mydata.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')
```

Pandas in the past has done a great job of picking the best date format.

However, When I do this now I'm getting my `DataFrame` back with the same text "APR2002"

As you would guess the last `to_period` will not work on that.

I have not change my code and I have not updated Pandas so I'm not sure where this change in coming from.

I'm not sure if I care too much about the why. What I really need help with is how do I format the index column to reflect Year-Month-Day or `%Y%m%d` as in 2005-04-30

I'm coming from R so any help would be huge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
 pd.to_datetime(mydata.pop('Date'), format="%b%Y")
```

but that would expect the date to appear like `Apr2002` (note not all caps).

You can specify a datetime format using the format string, and the format string will accept strftime arguments (defined [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)). There is some [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tseries.tools.to_datetime.html) on this too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DF = pd.read_csv('mydata.csv', parse_dates=[0])
```

Comment: Thanks.  This did not work for me.  I have seen people use this but I'm not sure how it is different the pd.read_csv('mydate.csv', parse_dates'True')  Which was not working for me either.  I'm getting a little confused since I'm not getting expect results.

Comment: OK, mostly the problem is in the format the values is stored in your csv file, could you post an extract of it? It works for me put probably because I hand-made the csv file from the example data you posted.